# Return Results for current or next weekend

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm creating a fixture list for football and would like to create a page "weekend fixtures".

I have managed the following

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 7
        or DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 1
        or (DATE_FORMAT(event_time, "%T") > '17:30:00' AND DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 6)
```

The above code works in returning fixtures for all weekends. But I need either the current or next.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: 'or' should be `OR`, are the code details up to date i.e. does it represent/fulfill your requirements if not what are the other columns/rows we should know about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [WEEK function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)  from mysql

This would check id´f event timestamp is in this or the next week

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 7
        or DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 1
        or (DATE_FORMAT(event_time, "%T") > '17:30:00' AND DAYOFWEEK(event_time) = 6))
        AND  ((WEEK(event_time) = WEEK(Now()) ) OR (WEEK(event_time) = WEEK(Now()) +1 ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved exactly what I asked. If I was to be picky, how would I only show next weekends results if this weekend has finished?

So at the moment its returning rest of this weekend and X amount of results from next up to current time.

Comment: when you follow the link in my answer you see there is also a mode, that you can add, Put the start of the week on monday(mode 1) this should help